# How to configure a Software RAID?

Tags: storage

What graphical tool can I use to configure for example 2 HDDs in a RAID 1?

Comment: please let me know whether my answer is useful or not..=)

Comment: I mean a GUI application, not a webinterface and not a graphical console application. For example on OS X you can drag and drop the disks you want to use in the RAID, select the FS and RAID Level and click create: http://turbo.paulstamatiou.com/uploads/2010/01/pstam_mbp_raid_array_precreate_740.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There is a GUI application called `system-config-lvm`, however it does not seem to work under elementary OS Loki.

Answer (score -2):

<s>Maybe GParted will do the job,</s> but if you don't want to use Webmin, I'm not aware of any other GUIs. Nothing stops you from programming one.

GParted is a powerful tool, but it is unsuitable for handling RAID.

Comment: This does not answer the question. You have stated Gparted cannot be used, but fail to suggest an alternative.